# Chrome extension XMLHttpRequest: Content Security Policy directive

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to access data from a website in my Chrome extension background page. However, I keep getting an error.

I packed the extension and installed it by drag-n-drop into chrome://extensions. It does ask me for permission to view all websites.

Manifest:

```
"permissions": ["webNavigation", "tabs", "*://*/*", "http://www.google.com/"],
```

Background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', "http://www.google.com", true);
    xhr.send();

}
```

Errors

Refused to connect to 'http://www.google.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Error in event handler for browserAction.onClicked: SecurityError: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Refused to connect to 'http://www.google.com/' because it violates the document's Content Security Policy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those two errors happen respectively because you're trying to make a request to a page without asking for the relative permissions, which have to be set in the **`"content_security_policy"` (CSP) field** of your extension's manifest, and because you're trying to connect to an insecure source: you need to **GET the page over `https://`** if you want to make it work, otherwise Chrome will reject your request.

Your CSP field in the manifest should look something like this:

```js
"content_security_policy": "default-src 'self' https://google.com"
```

See specific information about the CSP at the Chrome extension developer guide [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) and in the W3C documentation [here](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec/specs/content-security-policy/#connect-src-usage).

---

Anyway, even configuring the right CSP and loading over `https`, **Google still doesn't let you make `XMLHttpRequest`s to some of their pages** (like the main page, which is the one you're trying to access) **nor load them inside an `<iframe>`**, so even doing all right, **the request will be blocked on the server side**, producing the following error in JavaScript:

```
Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'https://google.com/'.
```

Stated the above, **since that it isn't possible to load/request `https://www.google.com/` directly, you just have to abandon any script you wish to create which involves doing so**.